# How does if (variable) { while(variable){...} } work in c programming?

Tags: c, pointers, if-statement, while-loop

I have a piece of code that has the following lines:

```
char* someString = "Blah"
char* someOtherString = someString;

if (someString) {
    while (*someOtherString) {
        printf("%d\n",someOtherString);
        ++someOtherString;
    }
    --someOtherString;
}
```

This prints out:

```
4206692
4206693
4206694
4206695
```

How does it even work? I get that it goes through the if statement as true because someString can be interpreted as a true condition, but how does it exit the while loop?

When I type the while loop by itself like so, I the loop goes infinitely:

```
 while (*someOtherString) {
     printf("%d\n",someOtherString);
     ++someOtherString;
}
```

Thanks for help in advanced!

Comment: When you say the loop goes infinitely, what was `someOtherString` initialized to?

Comment: I'm wrong about the infinite while loop. The reason while loop was running infinitely was because I initialized someOtherString as an integer 5. This was when I started looking into this loop and thought someOtherString was supposed to be an integer. It runs fine as aroth pointed out with ideone.

Comment: Please note that it is wrong to use the `%d` format specifier to print pointers, the correct format specifier for telling [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) that what you're printing is a pointer is `%p`. This is likely only to have a visible effect on platforms where pointer and integer have different sizes, but it's always Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The while loop exits when it finds the `NUL` character at the end of the "string".

---

#### Working :

In C, declaring and assigning constant strings inside double-quotes declares a **[null-terminated string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string)**. Memory equal to the
**number of characters in side the double-quotes** + *1 (for the trailing `NUL` character)* is allocated. Each of the characters is stored sequentially in the memory block and a `NUL` character is automatically assigned to the end of the memory block.

Thus "**Blah**" is stored in memory as
`B` `L` `A` `H` `\0`

Intially `someOtherString` and `someString` both point to `B`.

`someOtherString` is incremented to point to the next character in each iteration of the while loop. So after 4 iterations it ends up pointing to the null character.

> A while loop running on un-initialised data could run for a large
>   number of iterations as there is no guarantee that it will encounter a
>   `NUL` character (byte = `0x00`).

---

Finally a list of popular [functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling#Functions) and [extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling#Popular_extensions) for processing strings in C.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a technique to scan through a string.

When you just tell `char *string1 = "hello"` the *starting address* of the string will be stored inside the variable `char *string1` and not the string. One practice is to assign a pointer to `NULL` when it is not used, instead allowing the old address values in it, which now is not valid. Therefore if at some point we did `string1 = NULL`, then the `if (string1)` will be false, becaues `NULL` evaluates to 0.

```
            a1     a2    a3    a4    a5   a6
          +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
string1 = |  h  |  e  |  l  |  l  |  o  | \0  |
          +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Whereas when we do `*string1` it is basically in the form `*(string + x)`. Depending on the type of the pointer `string1` , `x` elements will be skipped first, then `*` will do the dereferencing at the location, `x` elements away from the address what is stored in `string1`.

```
            a1     a2    a3    a4    a5   a6
          +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
string1 = |  h  |  e  |  l  |  l  |  o  | \0  |
          +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
                               ^
                               |
                 +-------------+
                 |
 *(string1 + 3) same as string1[3]
```

Therefore doing `*string1` will fetch the value pointed by the address stored in `string1`.

Therefore

```
if (string1)
{
   while (*string1)
   {
      count++;
      string1++;
   }
}
```

This will enter the `if` iff the address stored in the string is not NULL, ie some valid address is assigned (if we follow the convention to assign NULL to unused). `*string` will be true until the address stored in `string1` in a specific iteration points to a non-zero value. C strings are terminated with a NUL character which is `'\0'` and has an ASCII value `0`. In each iteration we do `string1++`, this will increment the address value stored, and after each increment the value of `string1` will point to the next element adjacent (first `a1` then `a2` etc). When it points to the address where `'\0'` is stored, `*string1` will be 0 and `while (*string1)` is false thus breaks out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your string literal is stored in memory like:

`{'B', 'l', 'a', 'h', '\0'}`

...where '\0' is the null character (i.e. a character with a value of 0 when interpreted as an integer).

So eventually (after 4 increments), `*someOtherString` will evaluate to 0, which will be interpreted as `false` and end the loop.

I'm not sure how you're getting the infinite loop.  Your cut-down versions works just fine in ideone:  http://ideone.com/4fTDJb